# how to install nvidia drivers for Geforce 750M? (no bumblebee)

Tags: drivers, nvidia-optimus

Ubuntu 13.10, 64bit, Asus n550jv, Nvidia Geforce 750M

I wonder has anyone succeeded to install nvidia drivers in Ubuntu 13.10 64bit without bumblebee. And if yes - then what's the trick and exact steps to follow?

My steps are the following and it always leads to black screen with only cursor visible:

1. Ubuntu 13.10 fresh install and updates;
2. Download the latest nvidia driver for 750M (which at present moment is 331.49);
3. Go to terminal CTRL+ALT+F1;
4. Stop the lightdm service and execute the nvidia .run installer file;
5. Reboot

As a result I am always getting black screen after login .. only my cursor is visible and no idea what to do next!

Yes, i know how to install bumblebee and run with optirun, however I do not want to do that anymore and looking for pure nvidia solution without any third parties in the middle. Driver info says that it is for 750M then why isnt it running?

Please help, really desperate! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

It's `hybrid graphics` laptop. You can't install `nvidia` graphics driver directly. As i know NVIDIA doesn't work in `VGA`(low graphics mode or minimal graphics support) in hybrid system. You have to install bumblebee and configure bbswitch to always use the card(battery issue, no recommended).

Install [bumblebee-gui](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bumblebee-ui) to easily select application which you want to run with nvidia. To install bumblebee successfully in ubuntu 13.10 follow [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433018/bumblebee-error-in-ubuntu-13-10/435583#435583).

[image]